# How to skip to the next iteration of a loop based on if statement in python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, continue

I have two for loops which are iterating through a range and updating values in a list based on values found at a position in an array. The if clause in the second loop is performing a bitwise operation and using the position in list1 and val1 as the location to check in the array and the value at that position is compared to val2. val1 and val2 are updated every time the outer loop increments. If the if condition is met then some further values are updated.

```
for i in range(0, upper_bound-1):
    *** do some stuff ***
    val1 = func1[list1[n]
    val2 = func2[list1[n]

    for j in range(i+1, upper_bound):
        if (arr[list1[j], val1] & val2) !=0:
            t = list1[j]
            *** do some other stuff ***
```

What I want is that when a match is found according to the if statement then the value updates, but I only want the first match to be counted. So for example, if on the first iteration i = 0, in the inner loop a match is found at j = 10, then I want to move out of the inner loop and start again at the outer loop with i = 1. At the moment I might find more than one match in the inner loop, say j = 10 and j = 25,  but this is not what I want. I don't think continue would help in this situation. How might I address this problem?

Comment: I think `break` will be more suitable. It will help you get out of inner loop and continue with next iteration of outer loop.

Comment: use `break`?  ...